# rock,paper and scissors game using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone help and tell me what and where is the error. Click event on images is not working. Game is not functioning.[image]

My code-

```js
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
const userScore_span = document.getElementById('user-score');
const computerScore_span = document.getElementById('computer-score');
const result_p = document.querySelector('.result>p');
const scoreBoard_div = document.querySelector('.score-board');
const rock_div = document.getElementById('r');
const paper_div = document.getElementById('p');
const scissors_div = document.getElementById('s');


function getComputerChoice() {
  const choices = ['r', 'p', 's'];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return choices[randomNumber];
}

function convert() {
  if (letter === 'r') return 'rock';
  if (letter === 'p') return 'paper';
  if (letter === 's') return 'scissors';
}

function win(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  userScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  const smallUserWord = 'user'.fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallCompWord = 'comp'.fontsize(3).sub();
  result_p.innerHTML = convert(userChoice)(smallUserWord) + 'beats' + convert(computerChoice)(smallCompWord) + '.';

}

function lose(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  userScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  const smallUserWord = 'user'.fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallUserWord = 'comp'.fontsize(3).sub();
  result_p.innerHTML = convert(userChoice)(smallUserWord) + 'beats' + convert(computerChoice)(smallCompWord) + '.';
}

function draw(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  const smallUserWord = 'user'.fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallUserWord = 'comp'.fontsize(3).sub();
  result_p.innerHTML = convert(userChoice)(smallUserWord) + 'equals' + convert(computerChoice)(smallCompWord) + '.';
}

function game(userChoice) {
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  switch (userChoice + computerChoice) {
    case 'rs':
    case 'sp':
    case 'pr':
      win(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case 'rp':
    case 'ps':
    case 'sr':
      lose(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case 'rr':
    case 'ss':
    case 'pp':
      draw(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;

  }

}

function main() {
  rock_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game('r');
  });

  paper_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game('p');
  });

  scissors_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game('s');
  });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #24272e;
}

header {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

header>h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  color: #24272E;
}

.score-board {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid white;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.badge {
  background-color: #E2584D;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  color: white;
}

#user-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -40px;
}

#computer-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: -55px;
}

.result {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.choices {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.choice {
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.choice:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#action-message {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1> Rock Paper And Scissors</h1>
</header>
<div class="score-board">
  <div class='badge' id='user-label'>user</div>
  <div class='badge' id='computer-label'>comp</div>
  <span id='user-score'>0</span> :
  <!-- span is for inline and div is for block* -->
  <span id='computer-score'>0</span>
</div>
<div class='result'>
  <p>paper covers rock. You win!</p>
</div>
<div class='choices'>
  <div class='choice' id='r'>
    <img src='C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Javascript\projects\rock,paper,scissor\r.jpe'>
  </div>
  <div class='choice' id='p'>
    <img src='C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Javascript\projects\rock,paper,scissor\p.png'>
  </div>
  <div class='choice' id='s'>
    <img src='C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Javascript\projects\rock,paper,scissor\s.jpe'>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='action-message'>
  Make your move
</div>
```

I have used addEventListener on images. But nothing is happening. 
But the game is not working. Does it have to do something with images. Image formats?
Its a rock,paper,scissor game using pure javascript. When i click on any image it should update a score of user and computer should generate a random choice.
I have googled but could not find thing.

Comment: i see your events are called in main() function, did you call that function? You need to call it otherwise events will never be created

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. `smallUserWord` should be `smallCompWord` twice.

Comment: @Xufox, there are no errors. I checked them.

Comment: @Xufox why it should be twice? One is for 'user' and other is for 'comp'.

Comment: The console is not just for looking at errors. You can also use it to step through your code, set breakpoints, or less advanced, to view the output of `Console.log` commands that you can use for debugging.

Comment: @manumehra Yes, you _do_ get `SyntaxError: redeclaration of const smallUserWord` in the code you provided. The `win` function defines both constants `smallUserWord` and `smallCompWord`, whereas `lose` and `draw` define only the first constant twice. What I meant by _“`smallUserWord` should be `smallCompWord` twice”_ was that you need to replace the constant name in these two places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issues I can spot:**

- `main` attaches eventListeners but its never called.
- You are defining 2 variables with same name:

  `const smallUserWord = 'user'.fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallUserWord = 'comp'.fontsize(3).sub();`
- You have a function `convert` that returns a string but is used as if it returns a callback function:

```js
function convert() {
  if (letter === 'r') return 'rock';
  if (letter === 'p') return 'paper';
  if (letter === 's') return 'scissors';
}

function win(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  userScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  const smallUserWord1 = 'user'.fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallCompWord2 = 'comp'.fontsize(3).sub();
  result_p.innerHTML = convert(userChoice)(smallUserWord) + 'beats' + convert(computerChoice)(smallCompWord) + '.';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you achieve it

- using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in your `result_p.innerHTML`
- pass parameter in `convert` function
- brings code outside `main` function

You might want to use the word "gets beaten by" in your `lose` function `${convert(userChoice)}${smallUserWord} gets beaten by  ${convert(computerChoice)}${(smallCompWord)}.;` So that the user choice will always be the first word. But it's up to your preferences though

```js
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
const userScore_span = document.getElementById('user-score');
const computerScore_span = document.getElementById('computer-score');
const result_p = document.querySelector('.result>p');
const scoreBoard_div = document.querySelector('.score-board');
const rock_div = document.getElementById('r');
const paper_div = document.getElementById('p');
const scissors_div = document.getElementById('s');


function getComputerChoice() {
  const choices = ['r', 'p', 's'];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return choices[randomNumber];
}

function convert(letter) {
  if (letter === 'r') return 'rock';
  if (letter === 'p') return 'paper';
  if (letter === 's') return 'scissors';
}

function win(userChoice, computerChoice) {console.log('win');console.log(userChoice);console.log(computerChoice)
  userScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  const smallUserWord = 'user'.fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallCompWord = 'comp'.fontsize(3).sub();
  console.log(smallUserWord);console.log(smallCompWord)
  result_p.innerHTML = `${convert(userChoice)}${smallUserWord} beats  ${convert(computerChoice)}${(smallCompWord)}.`;

}

function lose(userChoice, computerChoice) {
console.log('lose');console.log(userChoice);console.log(computerChoice)
  computerScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  const smallUserWord = 'user'.fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallCompWord = 'comp'.fontsize(3).sub();
  result_p.innerHTML = `${convert(computerChoice)}${smallCompWord} beats  ${convert(userChoice)}${(smallUserWord)}.`;
}

function draw(userChoice, computerChoice) {
console.log('draw');console.log(userChoice);console.log(computerChoice)
  const smallUserWord = 'user'.fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallCompWord = 'comp'.fontsize(3).sub();
  result_p.innerHTML = `${convert(userChoice)}${smallUserWord} equals  ${convert(computerChoice)}${(smallCompWord)}.`;
}

function game(userChoice) {
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  switch (userChoice + computerChoice) {
    case 'rs':
    case 'sp':
    case 'pr':
      win(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case 'rp':
    case 'ps':
    case 'sr':
      lose(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case 'rr':
    case 'ss':
    case 'pp':
      draw(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;

  }

}


  rock_div.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    game('r');
  });

  paper_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game('p');
  });

  scissors_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game('s');
  });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #24272e;
}

header {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

header>h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  color: #24272E;
}

.score-board {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid white;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.badge {
  background-color: #E2584D;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  color: white;
}

#user-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -40px;
}

#computer-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: -55px;
}

.result {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.choices {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.choice {
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.choice:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#action-message {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1> Rock Paper And Scissors</h1>
</header>
<div class="score-board">
  <div class='badge' id='user-label'>user</div>
  <div class='badge' id='computer-label'>comp</div>
  <span id='user-score'>0</span> :
  <!-- span is for inline and div is for block* -->
  <span id='computer-score'>0</span>
</div>
<div class='result'>
  <p>paper covers rock. You win!</p>
</div>
<div class='choices'>
  <div class='choice' id='r'>
    <img src='C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Javascript\projects\rock,paper,scissor\r.jpe'>
  </div>
  <div class='choice' id='p'>
    <img src='C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Javascript\projects\rock,paper,scissor\p.png'>
  </div>
  <div class='choice' id='s'>
    <img src='C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Javascript\projects\rock,paper,scissor\s.jpe'>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='action-message'>
  Make your move
</div>
```